# IBOutletCollection of UIViewControllers

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I want to do something like `UITabBarController`. `UITabBarController` has property `viewControllers` into which I can add instances of `UIViewController *` in IB. I'm trying to do the same think with my own VC:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) IBOutletCollection(UIViewController) NSArray *viewControllers;
```

but this doesn't work. Is it even possible for us?

**EDIT 1.**

Ramshad posted the proper sample, but using XIB. I would like to achieve it using storyboards.

**EDIT 2. - at the end of bounty worth...**

I question vaderkvarn's post because in case of `UITabBarController` it works. Also as Ramshad posted, it is possible in NIBs. So far, dasblinkenlight's post is the most correct, but not answers the question. I'm holding this question opened because we shall find out if it's restricted for us or what is the way.

PS: Why these downvotes?

Comment: could you please explain your requirement ?

Comment: The question is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the outlet collection solution does not work is that a View Controller is not an outlet. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Outlet.html):

> An outlet is a property that is annotated with the symbol IBOutlet and
>   whose value you can set graphically in a nib file or a storyboard.

A view controller is not a graphical object.

If you want to use an IBOutletCollection, you should only use one view controller, and put the views in the collection.

But if you want one controller for every view, you need to go for a more programmatic approach. An array with view controllers might be a good start, but I couldn't say as I don't know what you want to do with them.

**Edit:**

To be more clear as you don't seem to catch my point:

No, it does not has to be a way. A Storyboard is not an API, it is a graphical tool for drawing scenes and segues. It is specially designed for things like Tab Bar based apps.

If you right click on your Storyboard file and choose *open as -> Source Code*, you will see that a Tab Bar Controller have special elements that other View Controllers do not have. To mess around with the XML in a Storyboard file is beyond me.

If you want to go with Nib files, use Ramshads answer.

If you want to get as close as possible with storyboards, go with dasblinkenlights answer.

But the answer to your question (as far as I know) is NO, there is no way to accomplish this with storyboards. If it were, it would have been documented, which it is not.

Comment: But `UITabBarViewController` works like this. If it's not part of private API, there has to be a way. It works even with NIB (as Ramshad posted). We shall find out if there is restriction in storyboards or what is the way.

Answer (score 2):

Although it does not look like you can connect `UIViewController`s to `IBOutletCollection`s (or there are too many restrictions placed on using them), there is a simple solution that works when you use storyboards. This code goes into your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
_viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
,   [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Controller1"]
,   [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Controller2"]
,   [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Controller3"]
,   nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done your requirement using  **`UISegmentedControl + IBOutletCollection + presentViewController`**.

You can use any control instead of **`UISegmentedControl`** as your wish.

I have Added 3 different **`UIViewControllers`** to **`Xib`** and labelled as **`ViewController1,2,3.`**

I also added 2 extra methods. One for presenting the corresponding view and another one for dismissing the earlier populated view.

I have attached the **`Xib`** settings screen-shot below.

You can use only one **`UIViewController`** instead of 3 and reuse it with some logic :)

**The methods are below:**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIViewController) NSArray *ViewCollection;

//dismissing the earlier populated view
- (IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


//presenting the corresponding view.
- (IBAction)resetAction:(id)sender {      

    UISegmentedControl *mySegment = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;

    int index = 0;          
    for (UIViewController *viewItem in _ViewCollection) {

        if (index == mySegment.selectedSegmentIndex) {

            [self presentViewController:viewItem animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        index++;
    }
}
```

You can download the my sample application from [**here**](http://www.filedropper.com/iboutletcollection)

**Xib Settings Screen-shot**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your sample. Yes, this is exactly the case, but I forgot mention, that I want to achieve this in storyboards. I'll update my question.

Comment: Then accept the answer and do it own using story boards. I have no time to create new sample apps regarding your question changes. Also Its not a place to ask sample apps :)
Read the faq before asking any questions. Else pray to god for avoid more down votes :) Happy coding..

Comment: Well, I'm sorry I did't mention storyboard at beginning. Problem isn't I need sample. Problem is IB don't let you connect view controllers to outlet collection in storyboard. That's my problem. I'am asking if someone knows if/how it is possible.

Comment: Ho.. I just mentioned :) any way try my sample app using story board.. if storyboards not allowing UIViewContollers, then proceed with UiViews as UIIBoutletCollection and change the method "resetAction" as per the changes .. good luck

Comment: Be sure I tried to do my storyboard sample before posting question. And I won't mess with views, I want to do it right with view controller containment pattern without `UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistencyException` or whatever cheating...